# High traffic page with URL change

Tags: redirect, seo, ranking

I have a page for a long time, and gives me about 20k page view per day, but now i will need to redesign the page, and moving it to a different URL , the page is now ranking #1 in Google, if i do a redirect point to my new URL or sub-domain, is it gonna affect my page ranking and traffic?

Answer (score 1):

Doing the 301 redirect from old URL to new one will help to transfer the  existing weightage. But once search engines gets to the page, all your content and other factors governs the ranking.